# How to use 1. (number followed by dot) format instead of [1] format in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

The editor asked me to use the following format.

> Reference
>   1. Author, blah blah

Instead of

> Reference
>   [1] Author, blah blah ...

Even though in the main text, [1] style has been used.

For example,

---

> Smith [1] has proposed ...
>
> Reference
>   1. Smith,

---

This is what I want.

Could you please advise how I can do the above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add the following to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

Comment: If you came here via internet search like me once: Here's a solution for biblatex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208821/dont-use-brackets-in-bibliography-1-instead-of-1

Comment: Perhaps you can improve this answer by telling how to change the format to `(1)`, which seems another FAQ. And adding a MWE (which four years ago wasn't fashionable).

Answer (score 2):

This one line should do if you are using `biblatex`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbold{#1\adddot}}
```

Credits to [@moewe's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171571/77071) for a similar question.

Comment: Or if you don't want the bold font: `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}`