# Bibliography style with no brackets

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use 1. (number followed by dot) format instead of [1] format in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-use-1-number-followed-by-dot-format-instead-of-1-format-in-bibliogra)

How to change my bibliography from:

[1] BlaBla

[2] BlaBla

to:

1. BlaBla
2. BlaBla

?