# Removing brackets from the reference

Tags: bibliographies, brackets, amsart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use 1. (number followed by dot) format instead of [1] format in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-use-1-number-followed-by-dot-format-instead-of-1-format-in-bibliogra)

I'm using the `amsart` class, and the command `\begin{thebibliography}` for references.

This puts all the enumerations of references in square brackets, and I want to get rid of this.

That is, I want the references to look like

```
1. ~~
2. ~~
```

rather than

```
[1]. ~~
[2]. ~~
```

How can this be achieved??

Comment: Use `\def\@biblabel#1{\@ifnotempty{#1}{#1}}`. Of course you need `makeatletter`

Comment: Hmm don't get what that means.. but thanks it just worked for me!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You should turn this into a proper answer so that Siyul can accept it.

Comment: Looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-use-1-number-followed-by-dot-format-instead-of-1-format-in-bibliography

Answer (score 5):

The square brackets are added in macro `\@cite` in class amsart. The following example
redefines the macro to omit the brackets.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\CheckCommand*{\@cite}[2]{%
  {%
    \@citestyle[\citeform{#1}\if@tempswa, #2\fi]%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\@cite}[2]{%
  {%
    \@citestyle\citeform{#1}\if@tempswa, #2\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
References \cite{abc} and \cite{def}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{abc} ABC.

\bibitem{def} DEF.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```