# How to get () instead of [] in bibliography list?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use 1. (number followed by dot) format instead of [1] format in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-use-1-number-followed-by-dot-format-instead-of-1-format-in-bibliogra)

I would like to use round parentheses () instead of square brackets [] for citations in a document that I'm working on.   I figured out how to get them in the text using the `round` option with `natbib`.  I can't figure out to have the generated bibliography to show () instead of [] when it lists the references.  What do I need to change to fix the way it formats the bibliography?

Comment: Similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-use-1-number-followed-by-dot-format-instead-of-1-format-in-bibliogra (and probably others).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{(#1)}
\makeatother
```

A minimal example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{xxyyzz.bib}
@article{author12,
    author = "The Author",
    title = "The Title",
    journal = "The journal",
    year = "2012"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{author12}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xxyyzz}

\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

The above method will work whether using `natbib` or not; as **Torbjørn T** mentions, with `natbib` you can simply say

```
\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{(#1)}
```

to obtain the same result.

Comment: The builtin `natbib` way would be `\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{(#1)}`. See section **2.12 Other formatting options**, page 15 in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I updated my answer adding your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @Phillip you're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer (click on the checkmark to the left, below the vote count).