# Rounded parenthesis in References

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to make my references have parentheses instead of brackets. I have

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```

in my preamble but when i did

```
\usepackage[super,round]{natbib}
```

that only changes how my citations look in the actual document.

I am looking for

> (1) Masaaki Aoki, et.al. Structural insight into ...etc..

instead of

> [1] Masaaki Aoki, et. al. ...etc

thanks,

J

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! What `\bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the edits! That looks much nicer than before.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66893/how-to-get-instead-of-in-bibliography-list/66895#66895 (also my comment to that answer) helps.