# Bibliography style numeration with parentheses instead of square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, achemso

I'm trying to set the enumeration style in my bibliography into parentheses instead of square brackets. I was not able to find a solution for it. I'm not talking about the in-text citation style, just about the enumeration style in the Bibliography. Here you can see the general structure of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}



\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

My goal is, that my Bibliography style looks like

[image]

I have no experience with this or any forum at all. So if my question does not fit the formalities just let me know.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you consider using biblatex?

Comment: Hey Bernard, thank you, that you relpyed that quickly. I would consider it, if there is no quicker way. Though I have to admit, I have no experience with biblatex at all. How long do you think, would it take to solve my problem?

Comment: Hey there everyone, I foudd a solution to my problem. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66893/how-to-get-instead-of-in-bibliography-list?rq=1 thank you very much though!