# how do you fix the list of references at the end of article so that they are (#) rather than [# ]?

Tags: bibliographies

How do I fix the list of references at the end of an article so that they appear as 
 (1) rather than [1]?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that indicates how the bibliography is being created: Entirely by hand, with bibtex, or the biblatex package? If it's one of the two latter methods, please also indicate which bibliography style you use. Do also state which document class you use.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14183

Comment: In Gonzalo's answer, just change `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}` into `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{(#1)}`