# Change .bst file to eliminate brackets in reference list

Tags: bibtex

I need a reference list in the format

```
1. ...
2. ...
```

instead of

```
[1] ...
[2] ...
```

I would like to know what to change in a .bst file, e.g. [naturemag.bst](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/nature/naturemag.bst), to achieve that.

I want to do this without calling extra packages and without adding any new definitions to the preamble, because such approach has been already  explored [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/how-to-use-1-number-followed-by-dot-format-instead-of-1-format-in-bibliogra).

Comment: The LaTeX document class usually provides a basic definition of the `thebibliography` environmen. It's in in this definition that you'll find`[` and `]` being use to surround the item numbers. (The `naturemag` bibliography style does *not* redefine the `thebibliography` environment.) Which document class do you use?

Comment: I am using the book class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `book` document class provides the following default setup for the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\chapter*{\bibname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

The `book` document class also provides the following definitions for `\bibindent` and `\bibname`:

```
\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}
\newcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
```

The macro `\@biblabel` is defined as follows in the LaTeX kernel (see `latex.ltx`):

```
\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]}
```

The `\list` and `\endlist` instructions are also defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Unless a citation management package -- e.g., `natbib`, `harvard`, or `cite`, which provides its own definitions of these macros -- is loaded, the default definitions will be used in your document.

---

Let's examine the first argument of `\list`:

```
\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}
```

You can probably guess that `\@arabic\c@enumiv` generates the arabic-numeral representation of the counter `enumiv` and that `\@biblabel{...}` encases this numeral in square brackets -- unless, of course, `\@biblabel` has been changed, either by hand or by having loaded a suitable LaTeX package.

To sum up, if you want the numeric "labels" that are placed before the bib items *not* to appear as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc, and if you don't want to load a suitable package (say, `natbib`) to handle this chore, you need to modify the `\@biblabel` macro "by hand". That's what was done in the answer you linked to in your posting:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

Finally, as the bibliography style `naturemag` does *not* modify the `thebibliography` environment, editing `naturemag.bst` won't let you achieve your stated formatting goal.